# Is it bad to return same property in get accessor? public string ProjectID { get { return ProjectID; } etc

Tags: c#-4.0, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a simple class that I want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I don't need to have a private version of this property. The class is being passed via a WCF service and a Silverlight client.

My question: Is it OK to structure the get accessor this way? Just does not seem right to me.

```
public ProjectID
{
   get
   {
      return this.ProjectID;
   }
   set
   {
      ProjectID = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("ProjectID");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code above will throw a stack overflow exception, you may have to implement a member to support the interface you want to

Comment: This is exactly what I thought the issue would be. Thanks to you and Closure Cowboy.

Answer (score 1):

That would result in a `StackOverflowException`, because the `get` property would keep recursively calling itself.